# fix btrfs "btrfs parent transid verify failed on ..."

Tags: linux, filesystems, repair, btrfs

`btrfs fi show` displays all btrfs file system but also a lot of errors like:

> parent transid verify failed on 109973766144 wanted 1823 found 1821

The filesystem can still be unmounted and remounted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surfing the web I found a lot of [answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32440/how-do-i-fix-btrfs) recommending to clear `btrfs`' internal log by using `btrfs-zero-log`. I thought [`btrfsck`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfsck) could help but eventually I discovered the [official recommendation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfsck) which is to ***first just start a [`btrfs scrub`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-scrub)*** before taking other actions!

So just run `btrfs scrub /path/to/mountpoint` if you too can still mount your filesystem. And maybe it works like in my case.

Answer (score 11):

### Beware of btrfs-zero-log

[btrfs-zero-log documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Btrfs-zero-log) states clearly that it's not a generic tool to use:

> btrfs-zero-log **is not a general fix-everything tool**, **despite what many people believe and state around the internet**. You generally don't need to use it.

So there is only single use case for this tools: when you see the `BTRFS: failed to read log tree` message in your logs.

### Fixing *parent transid verify failed* errors with `usebackuproot`

The 3.2 Linux kernel [introduced in January 2012](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#v3.2_.28Jan_2012.29) the `recovery` option.
Then, in May 2016 with the 4.6 version, [it was superseded](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Changelog#v4.6_.28May_2016.29) by `usebackuproot`.
You can also see [the commit](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-btrfs/patch/1453170184-22869-2-git-send-email-quwenruo@cn.fujitsu.com/#17472101) if you're interested.

The [documentation](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5)) explains clearly what it does:

```
usebackuproot
nousebackuproot

    (since: 4.6, default: off)

    Enable autorecovery attempts if a bad tree root is found at mount time.
    Currently this scans a backup list of several previous tree roots and
    tries to use the first readable. This can be used with read-only mounts as well.

    Note: This option has replaced recovery.
```

A [note in the official FAQ section](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#How_do_I_recover_from_a_.22parent_transid_verify_failed.22_error.3F) states that this is the right way to fix this "parent transid" error:

> How do I recover from a "parent transid verify failed" error?
>
> For example:
>
> `parent transid verify failed on 29360128 wanted 1486656 found 1486662`
>
> If the second two numbers (wanted 1486656 and found 1486662) are close
> together (within about 20 of each other), then mounting with
>
> `-o ro,usebackuproot`
>
> may help. If it's successful with a read-only mount, then try again
> without the `ro` option, for a read-write mount.
>
> **If the usebackuproot doesn't work, then the FS is basically unrecoverable** in its current state with current tools. You should use btrfs restore to refresh your backups, and then restore from them.

### Commands to use

> These commands are just example of a failed btrfs disk on a Fedora installation.
> Replace `/dev/sda2` with your device and `/sysroot` with your mount point

First try in read only mode:

```
mount -t btrfs -o ro,usebackuproot /dev/sda2 /sysroot
```

If that works, try again without the readonly command:

```
mount -t btrfs -o usebackuproot /dev/sda2 /sysroot
```

Now, if that command have worked without errors, your should be able to boot your Linux.

Comment: Mounting it will not make it to pass btrfsck

Comment: My sincere gratitude to you. After many hours of troubleshooting various approaches to this issue (unable to mount a raw btrfs image), your suggestion of using the usebackuproot option resolved the problem.
I can also confirm that- in my case- the parent transid verify check was only off by one.

Answer (score 5):

First run this command:

`sudo btrfs rescue super-recover -v /dev/sda2`

If it tells you *“All supers are valid, no need to recover”*, you need to run the following command to clear the filesystem log tree:

`sudo btrfs rescue zero-log /dev/sda2`

Now you should be able to mount your `Btrfs` file system.

Comment: This command worked for me even though the other commands above did not. This command found two good supers and one bad super. After I confirmed the filesystem was indeed BTRFS, it went ahead and recovered the 1 bad super. After that, I was able to boot successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I faced a similar situation:

1. *logs* were full with `parent transid verify failed on 109973766144 wanted 1823 found 1821`
2. *dmesg* was full with `BTRFS info (device sda): no csum found for inode 16485445 start 73728` and `BTRFS warning (device sda): csum failed ino 16485465 off 36864 csum 2268363541 expected csum 0`

**configuration of my system**

3. NAS with 3 nfs shares
4. BTRFS file system
5. Rockstor Operating System
6. RAID 10 setup

**additional information**

7. the btrfs mount became read only
8. btrfs-scrub failed with `ERROR: scrubbing /dev/md124p2 failed for device id 1: ret=-1, errno=5`

I solved it by deleting the nfs export ie. from /etc/export/ and then remounting the volumes and voila everything became ok

**UPDATE 29 Jan 2018:** after working for a few days it went back exactly to the same state

Comment: I experienced a very similar issue: 4HDDs in RAID 10 with madm, BTRFS file system (ubuntu 18.04, kernel 4.18), access over samba. 
`dmesg` reported a lot of errors similar to your error, a quarter of all files could not be opened (`I/O error`), `btrfs scrub` failed with the same error code. Disabling the samba service and remounting the file system cured all problems like a charm. I will now setup a new NAS configuration with ext4 instead of btrfs as I do not trust this file system any more. Seems like there is a bug when interacting with nfs/samba in such configurations?!

Answer (score -1):

Similar/Same problem here:

`parent transid verify failed on 29605888 wanted 50 found 46`

---

For me the btrfs is not mountable anymore so `btrfs scrub` is no option.
Also my `/etc/exports` are empty.

I tried `btrfsck --init-extent-tree /dev/sda4` but I still get errors.

```sh
    ...
    btrfs check(main+0x82)[0x411ba2]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f8210fab555]
    btrfs check[0x411ca8]
    Aborted
    #
```

Link to Screenshot (Updload wasn't possible):
[Screenshot](https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/AA49IrYkM3-Go31PE_Ic3psvDE94Fle-HKE0G3-fjMWEGsPgJiBgSwStAPYP6yS1ric8wmNkR3MsIUR1N2NTkD6ZpDzU6EhiKi9LhQE2Iu6l00ZSA8HaE3lWdTzRWZmtzTUDhSTT_j0sEh56DQa99fcbyXheoBVLpbD-GiriI_9z8OFBBETgN9isuohUpobZvBA6tx-xkefpWNwxOQ_X_X7hFKsMYkxK_Vb_TfnnkVCJq3R_AYsjR6AATLY2yb3aIZOzpzqECPWw2jxywQFIaVfgFEz9nHEkIjEGuFDlFMGKEM8hx_aOPogbCj7Zdo_5HIMXw7ZyEoLINrGi3yEbuSbZcADQzOaQ_J_SlB2FkViNlQ/p.png?fv_content=true&size_mode=5)

It seems the only solution is to restore the data to another disk by

```
btrfs restore /dev/sda4 /mnt/anotherdisk/folder
```

.

Comment: If you restored data to another disk, how do you make the old drive (here: /dev/sda4) usable again? Formatting?

Comment: It was a virtual machine with virtual disks, so I created a new virtual disk. the restore also did not recover all mysql files well so the system was crashed forever.